# Podio Rate Limit decreased

Tags: podio

Do you know why RateLimit is 60?

If docs say "The general limit is 1,000 API calls per hour".

One week ago the limit was fine but these days changed.

I am creating a workspace from the `podio-php`, each workspace has 4 apps by default and each of them has hooks, the problem is when I try to verify the hooks.

So, this is my global function to call the API:

```
function initPodio()
{
     Podio::setup(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, array(
        "session_manager" => "PodioBrowserSession"
     ));

    if (!Podio::is_authenticated()) {
         try {
             Podio::authenticate_with_password(USER, PASSWORD);
         } catch (PodioError $e) {
            // Something went wrong. Examine $e->body['error_description'] for a description of the error.
         }
    }
}
```

I called every time I need to use podio library, for example: when I created a workspace:

```
initPodio();
$podio_space = PodioSpace::create($attributes);
```

or when I need to create an item of an app.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify which request is returning this error

Comment: Do you maintain podio-php-session? If it's new session for each request, then session manager is not working :( Effectively, there is new login request for each call.

Comment: Greetings @Pavlo-Podio , the podio-php-session is maintained. I have already done several tests creating workspaces, apps and items and limit is maintained.
Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I’m glad it’s solved, Please accept answer if it helped, this way others will be able to reuse it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting rate limit error from Podio authentication end-point. Please update your question with full request and response, that will definitely help understanding your case.

To avoid rate limiting on authentication, please store and re-use `access_token` and `refresh_token` (they are available after initial login). There is no need to re-authenticate with each request. This is explained in more details here: https://developers.podio.com/authentication

Examples of session management implemented for different Podio clients could be found here:

- http://podio.github.io/podio-dotnet/sessions/
- http://podio.github.io/podio-php/sessions/